# Generate RFC 3339 timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601, rfc3339

I'm trying to generate an [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) UTC timestamp in Python. So far I've been able to do the following:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print d.isoformat('T')
2011-12-18T20:46:00.392227
```

My problem is with setting the UTC offset.

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html), the classmethod `datetime.now([tz])`, takes an optional `tz` argument where `tz must be an instance of a class tzinfo subclass`, and `datetime.tzinfo` is `an abstract base class for time zone information objects.`

This is where I get lost- How come tzinfo is an abstract class, and how am I supposed to implement it?

---

(**NOTE:** In PHP it's as simple as `timestamp = date(DATE_RFC3339);`, which is why I can't understand why Python's approach is so convoluted...)

Comment: [Further down](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) in the same doc that you linked to, it explains how to implement it, giving some examples, including full code for a `UTC` class (representing UTC), a `FixedOffset` class (representing a timezone with a fixed offset from UTC, as opposed to a timezone with DST and whatnot), and a few others.

Comment: @ruakh- thanks, I missed those examples- The `LocalTimezone()` class did the trick.

Comment: Just found this similar question: [ISO Time (ISO 8601) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python)

Answer (score 98):

*UPDATE 2021*

In Python 3.2 `timezone` was added to the datetime module allowing you to easily assign a timezone to UTC.

```
import datetime

n = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
n.isoformat() # '2021-07-13T15:28:51.818095+00:00'
```

*previous answer:*

Timezones are a pain, which is probably why they chose not to include them in the datetime library.

try pytz, it has the tzinfo your looking for:
http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

You need to first create the `datetime` object, then apply the timezone like as below, and then your `.isoformat()` output will include the UTC offset as desired:

```
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
d_with_timezone = d.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
d_with_timezone.isoformat()
```

> '2017-04-13T14:34:23.111142+00:00'

Or, just use UTC, and throw a "Z" (for *Zulu* timezone) on the end to mark the "timezone" as UTC.

```
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # <-- get time in UTC
print d.isoformat("T") + "Z"
```

> '2017-04-13T14:34:23.111142Z'

Comment: @monkut- thanks- The pytz class looks like another implementation that would work, but I ended up using the example included in the docs, per ruakh's answer.

Comment: it doesn't return microseconds for me :-/

Answer (score 45):

In Python 3.3+:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone                                
>>> local_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()
>>> local_time.isoformat()
'2015-01-16T16:52:58.547366+01:00'
```

On older Python versions, if all you need is an aware datetime object representing the current time in UTC then you could [define a simple tzinfo subclass as shown in the docs to represent UTC timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421145/4279):

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_now = datetime.now(utc)
print(utc_now.isoformat('T'))
# -> 2015-05-19T20:32:12.610841+00:00
```

You could also use [`tzlocal` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal) to get `pytz` timezone representing your local timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

now = datetime.now(get_localzone())
print(now.isoformat('T'))
```

It works on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Hands down, best answer for Python 3.3+

Comment: Technically, ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 aren't 100% compatible...some differences exist, such as that ISO 8601 allows either a minus sign or a hyphen for the UTC offset part, whereas RFC 3339 _only_ allows a hyphen. Every `.isoformat()` implementation I've seen so far (only a couple) does overlap with RFC 3339, but it's good to make yourself aware of the differences

Comment: @villapx: rfc 3339 is a profile of ISO 8601. It happens that `datetime.isoformat()` is RFC 3339 for a timezone-aware datetime (that is why I've used it).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, it seems you're right...from the docs, `isotime()` `[gives] the UTC offset in (signed) hours and minutes: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm+HH:MM`, which is RFC 3339. It doesn't explicitly say it will use a hyphen as opposed to a minus sign, but it's implied by the examples

Comment: Although, `isoformat()` doesn't look at the daylight savings time offset for the `tzinfo` object--as I change the `dst()` return value, `isoformat()` still returns the same string

Comment: @villapx: `isoformat()` returns the correct value It just reflects what `datetime` object contains. Namely, it shows its `.utcoffset()` value.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Right, that's what I mean--just wanted to make potential users aware that `isoformat()` isn't aware of DST

Comment: @villapx: no, it is wrong. You are misleading the "potential users". If `.utcoffset()` doesn't reflect `.dst()` value then your `datetime` class is broken.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh wow, you're right. I was totally misled by the `datetime.tzinfo.dst()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.dst): `Note that DST offset, if applicable, has already been added to the UTC offset returned by utcoffset(), so there’s no need to consult dst() unless you’re interested in obtaining DST info separately.` I did not see directly above that, for `utcoffset()`, where it says, `"Note that this is intended to be the total offset from UTC."`

Comment: Can't it be just `datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().isoformat()`? `now()` returns a naive object and `astimezone()` sets the local timezone.

Comment: @jrc: now() by itself may be ambiguous (e.g., during a DST transition).

Answer (score 15):

On modern (3.x) python, to get RFC 3339 UTC time, all you need to do is use datetime and this single line (no third-party modules necessary):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
```

The result is something like: '2019-06-13T15:29:28.972488+00:00'

This ISO 8601 string is also RFC3339 compatible.

Comment: Actually the Python datetime is not compatible with ISO 8601, as it doesn't allow strings ending with 'Z'

Comment: Exactly. How can I get the Z ending though?

Comment: @uwieuwe4 you can just use `.replace('+00:00', 'Z')` on the above result.  Or, just use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` instead of .isoformat().

Comment: Python 3.11 can now parse datetimes with Z suffix: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#datetime

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with RFC3339 datetime format a lot, but I found a suitable solution to convert date_string <=> datetime_object in both directions.

You need two different external modules, because one of them is is only able to do the conversion in one direction (unfortunately):

first install:

```
sudo pip install rfc3339
sudo pip install iso8601
```

then include:

```
import datetime     # for general datetime object handling
import rfc3339      # for date object -> date string
import iso8601      # for date string -> date object
```

For not needing to remember which module is for which direction, I wrote two simple helper functions:

```
def get_date_object(date_string):
  return iso8601.parse_date(date_string)

def get_date_string(date_object):
  return rfc3339.rfc3339(date_object)
```

which inside your code you can easily use like this:

```
input_string = '1989-01-01T00:18:07-05:00'
test_date = get_date_object(input_string)
# >>> datetime.datetime(1989, 1, 1, 0, 18, 7, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-05:00' datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)>)

test_string = get_date_string(test_date)
# >>> '1989-01-01T00:18:07-05:00'

test_string is input_string # >>> True
```

Heureka! Now you can easily (*haha*) use your date strings and date strings in a useable format.

Comment: "Heureka". Lose the 'H'.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful utility I just started working with: [dateutil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/1.5) library for timezone handling and date parsing. Recommended around SO, including this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908349/165673)

Comment: `dateutil` is a library that offers functionality for *parsing* dates to datetime, I don't think this is helpful in the context of *generating* date/time strings with a certain format.

Answer (score 1):

The [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) package is available for Python 2.X and 3.X. It implements concrete subclasses of `tzinfo`, among other services, so you don't have to.

To add a UTC offset:
    import datetime
    import pytz

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 18, 20, 46, 00, 392227)
utc_dt = pytz.UTC.localize(dt)
```

And now this:

```
print utc_dt.isoformat()
```

would print:

```
2011-12-18T20:46:00.392227+00:00
```

Comment: you don't need `pytz` module if all you want is UTC timezone. It is simple to [define utc tzinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25421145/4279)

Comment: Thanks. I'll save your answer for when I need an stdlib solution.
UTC was just the shortest to demonstrate. OP didn't specifically ask for it.
`pytz` knows about all timezones and their DST, which I find useful.

Comment: Note: [`get_localzone()` in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27987813/4279) returns puts timezone that corresponds to the local timezone.

Comment: Yes. It should be" `pytz` timezone", not "`puts ` timezone"

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use the built-in
[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. As
[@ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)
[mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556584/168874), there are examples in the
page that show how. If you look into the section on
[tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) you'll
see a long example showing many different use cases. Here's the code for the one
you're looking for, which is to generate an RFC 3339 UTC timestamp.

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
import time as _time

ZERO = timedelta(0)
STDOFFSET = timedelta(seconds=-_time.timezone)
if _time.daylight:
    DSTOFFSET = timedelta(seconds=-_time.altzone)
else:
    DSTOFFSET = STDOFFSET

DSTDIFF = DSTOFFSET - STDOFFSET


class LocalTimezone(tzinfo):

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        if self._isdst(dt):
            return DSTOFFSET
        else:
            return STDOFFSET

    def dst(self, dt):
        if self._isdst(dt):
            return DSTDIFF
        else:
            return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return _time.tzname[self._isdst(dt)]

    def _isdst(self, dt):
        tt = (dt.year, dt.month, dt.day,
              dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second,
              dt.weekday(), 0, 0)
        stamp = _time.mktime(tt)
        tt = _time.localtime(stamp)
        return tt.tm_isdst > 0

Local = LocalTimezone()

d = datetime.now(Local)
print d.isoformat('T')

# which returns
# 2014-04-28T15:44:45.758506-07:00
```