# Does python time.strftime process timezone options correctly (for RFC 3339)

Tags: python, time, strftime

I'm trying to get RFC3339 compatible output from python's time module, using the time.strftime() function.

With the Linux 'date' command, I can use a format string like the following: "date +%F_%T%:z"

```
$ date +%F_%T%:z
2017-06-29_16:13:29-07:00
```

When used with python time.strftime, the %:z appears to not be supported.

```
$ python
>>> import time
>>> print time.strftime("%F %T%:z")
2017-06-29 16:16:15%:z
```

Apparently, '%z' is supported, but '%:z' is not:

```
>>> print time.strftime("%F %T%z")
2017-05-29 16:15:35-0700
```

RFC3339 specifically uses the timezone offset with the embedded colon.
That would be 07:00 in my case, instead of 0700.

I believe the omission of support for the "%:z' option is due to the underlying C implementation of strftime() not supporting the versions of timezone offset formatters with colons.  That is '%:z', '%::z', etc.

Is there any workaround for this (e.g. another python module, or some option I'm missing int the 'time' module), other than writing code to get %z output and reformat it in %:z format, to solve this problem?

EDIT: Another question ([Generate RFC 3339 timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python)) gives solutions for other modules that can be used to output RFC3339 output.  I'm going to self-answer with information that I found for the question in the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate RFC 3339 timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python)

Comment: There is a [RFC3339](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc3339) module on PyPI that might do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strict answer to the question in the title "Does python time.strftime process timezone options correctly (for RFC3339)?" is: No.

The "%:z" supported by the Linux 'date' command is a GNU extension, and is not in the POSIX spec, or in the C implementation of strftime (as of this writing).

With regards to workarounds (requested in the body of the question), answers in [Generate RFC 3339 timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python) can be used as alternatives time.strftime to output RFC3339-compliant software.

Specifically, I used the pytz module to get timezone information, and datetime class isoformat() function to print in RFC3339-compliant format (with a colon in the timezone offset portion of the output).  Like so:
(in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
>>> import pytz, datetime
>>> latz = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
>>> latz
<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now(latz)
>>> dt2 = datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, 0, latz)
>>> dt2.isoformat()
'2017-07-06T11:50:07-08:00'
```

Note the conversion from dt to dt2, to set microseconds to 0.  This prevents isoformat from printing microseconds as a decimal portion of seconds in the isoformat output (which RFC3339 does not support)