# ValueError: Unknown protobuf attr type <type 'datetime.date'>

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Getting an error in executing the code. I have a datastore entity which has a property of type Date. An example date property value stored in an entity for a particular row is **2016-01-03 (19:00:00.000) EDT**

The code i am executing is filtering the entity values based on date greater than 2016-01-01. Any idea what is wrong with the code

**Error**

```
ValueError: Unknown protobuf attr type <type 'datetime.date'>
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

from google.cloud import datastore
from flask import Flask,Blueprint
app = Flask(__name__)

computation_cron= Blueprint('cron.stock_data_transformation', __name__)
@computation_cron.route('/cron/stock_data_transformation')
def cron():
ds = datastore.Client(project="earningspredictor-173913")
query = ds.query(kind='StockPrice')
query.add_filter('date', '>', datetime.strptime("2016-01-01", '%Y-%m-%d').date())

dataframe_data = []
temp_dict = {}
for q in query.fetch():
    temp_dict["stock_code"] = q["stock_code"]
    temp_dict["date"] = q["date"]
    temp_dict["ex_dividend"] = q["ex_dividend"]
    temp_dict["split_ratio"] = q["split_ratio"]
    temp_dict["adj_open"] = q["adj_open"]
    temp_dict["adj_high"] = q["adj_high"]
    temp_dict["adj_low"] = q["adj_low"]
    temp_dict["adj_close"] = q["adj_close"]
    temp_dict["adj_volume"] = q["adj_volume"]
    dataframe_data.append(temp_dict)
sph = pd.DataFrame(data=dataframe_data,columns=temp_dict.keys())
# print sph.to_string()
query = ds.query(kind='EarningsSurprise')
query.add_filter('act_rpt_date', '>', datetime.strptime("2016-01-01", '%Y-%m-%d').date())

dataframe_data = []
temp_dict = {}
for q in query.fetch():
    temp_dict["stock_code"] = q["stock_code"]
    temp_dict["eps_amount_diff"] = q["eps_amount_diff"]
    temp_dict["eps_actual"] = q["eps_actual"]
    temp_dict["act_rpt_date"] = q["act_rpt_date"]
    temp_dict["act_rpt_code"] = q["act_rpt_code"]
    temp_dict["eps_percent_diff"] = q["eps_percent_diff"]
    dataframe_data.append(temp_dict)
es = pd.DataFrame(data=dataframe_data,columns=temp_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Where's the model definition?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using the generic [`google-cloud-datastore`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library) client library, not the [NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/).

For `google-cloud-datastore` all date and/or time properties have the same format. From [Date and time](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#date_and_time):

> - JSON
>
>   - field name: `timestampValue`
>   - type: string (RFC 3339 formatted, with milliseconds, for instance `2013-05-14T00:01:00.234Z`)
> - Protocol buffer
>
>   - field name: `timestamp_value`
>   - type: `Timestamp`
> - Sort order: Chronological
> - Notes: When stored in Cloud Datastore, precise only to microseconds; any additional precision is rounded down.

So when setting/comparing such properties try to use strings formatted as specified (or integers for protobuf [Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/timestamp)?), not directly objects from the `datetime` modules (which work with the NDB library). The same *might* be true for queries as well.

Note: this is based on documentation only, I didn't use the generic library myself.

Comment: How do i build  a RFC 3339 formatted timestamp (2016-01-03 (19:00:00.000) EDT) value in python for comparsion to another timestamp value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python

Comment: Getting an error File "/Users/Ram/fintech-api/flex/internal/cron/stock_data_transformation.py", line 3, in <module>
    from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime, timezone
ImportError: cannot import name timezone