# How to convert unix time to Google API datetime format using python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to convert a **UNIX** time like `1522922431 (Unix time)` into **RFC 3339** format used by Google API `2018-04-05T10:00:31+00:00 (RFC 3339)` using python. Is it possible using any python packages or python modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: (Re-) **Search** before asking questions. Use the answers provided in the dupe to create a `datetime` and then format it as you like using [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) or use the answers provided in  [generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python)

Comment: It was supposed to be more specific question than the generalized answer, to be used for Google API, does it change the relevance?

Comment: Markandeya - then code one. SO is not a "coding service for what I want" - it is a forum where you give your code that you have problems with and we help you fix it. Use the links provided, code your solution and if you _then_ have got problems, ask a question providing your [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PatrickArtner True, but why code when there are inbuilt functions that can be used?

Comment: Coding is the way of chaining inbuild things - did you even read the questions I linked you too and viewed the answers on them? They solve your problem ... thats kindof the definition of duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` and `pytz` library

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

utc = pytz.utc
a_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1522922431)
utc_date = utc.localize(a_date).isoformat()
'2018-04-05T10:00:31+00:00'
```

Comment: What is pytz used for?

Comment: To allow conversion of `datetime` objects between different timezones. See http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Markandeya Just made a slight change, I was using the `fromtimestamp` method, it should have been the `utcfromtimestamp` method

Comment: valid solution for a question that is a dupe :) I mostly do not answer dupes but thats preference. +1

Comment: All good, always happy to help out. Even though the question is a duplicate I do find that I get personal benefit from putting together my own solution. In this instance for this question I discovered the differences between the `.utcfromtimestamp` and `.fromtimestamp` methods