# How to convert this time to utc for google api to take it?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a script that needs utc as an input:

This gives me the time format I need, but the wrong time:

```
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
```

I want to be able to set the time in a format like this but have it output in utc.

```
time = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, 12, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
time = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, 12, 0, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
```

Here is more conversation about the topic: [Generate RFC 3339 timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556398/generate-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-python)