# Timestamp subtraction in ISO8601

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp, iso8601

I have a timestamp like this: `2021-01-03T01:59:00Z`.
How can I write a subtraction to get the timestamp a day earlier than the one indicated in ISO 8601 format?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this might be closed as a combination-dupe of e.g. [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418) and [Generate RFC 3339 timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556398/10197418) (of which the latter again is closed as dupe although RFC3339 is only a subset of ISO8601)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delta for take away 1 day

```
your_timestamp = '2021-01-03T01:59:00Z'
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(your_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Simpler and more efficient [datetime.fromisoformat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418). And I think the OP wants output in ISOformat string as well (so just reverse the oparation by `datetimeobject.isoformat` method or `strftime`).

Comment: Hi, I try it but I have this error
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @lucacanonico: use `import datetime` and not `from datetime import datetime`. The latter import just one class, but we need also `timedelta`. It just make you some more typing, but less confusing (IMO)

Comment: @MrFuppes i checked it. 
in my variant it take 6.47 µs ± 72.3 ns per loop
if i use your variant, it's takes 196 ns ± 0.563 ns per loop.
So your variant more faster

Comment: @MaksymSivash well, faster is sometimes less pretty (as in this case...), so `strptime` is fine if OP has to do this operation like once in a while. But I think you should add the output to ISO-format to your answer as well.

Comment: @MrFuppes yes I would like to get the timestamp in ISOformat string; Maksym Sivah method is usefull but don't answer my question

Comment: @lucacanonico e.g. `result.isoformat(timespec='seconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z')` should work