# Python date iso8601 format with timezone designator

Tags: python

I'm sending some dates from  server that has it's time in gmt-6 format, but when i convert them to isoformat i don't get the tz designator at the end.

I'm currently setting the date like this:

```
date.isoformat()
```

but I'm getting this string: `2012-09-27T11:25:04` without the tz designator.

how can I do this?

Comment: [This answer on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147286/1717535) has a section with "UTC to ISO 8601 with TimeZone information (Python 3)".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not getting the timezone designator because the `datetime` is not aware (ie, it doesn't have a `tzinfo`):

```python
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().isoformat()
'2012-09-27T14:24:13.595373'
>>> tz = pytz.timezone("America/Toronto")
>>> aware_dt = tz.localize(datetime.now())
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 27, 14, 25, 8, 881440, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Toronto' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
>>> aware_dt.isoformat()
'2012-09-27T14:25:08.881440-04:00'
```

In the past, when I've had to deal with an unaware `datetime` which I know to represent a time in a particular timezone, I've simply appended the timezone:

```python
>>> datetime.now().isoformat() + "-04:00"
'2012-09-27T14:25:08.881440-04:00'
```

Or combine the approaches with:

```python
>>> datetime.now().isoformat() + datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/Toronto")).isoformat()[26:]
'2012-09-27T14:25:08.881440-04:00'
```

Comment: Ok I thought of appending the tz, but I didn't know the format, I guess it would be -06:00. But what is the 881440 portion, is that part of the timezone?

Comment: Ah, my current time string doesn't include that, would it still work without them?

Comment: For directly generating in UTC: ```datetime.now(pytz.utc)```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to deal with dates with a specialized module such as [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [`delorean`](https://delorean.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.now().isoformat()
'2020-11-25T08:10:39.672624+01:00'
```