# Convert date value in a list

Tags: python

I have a list containing date values in this format (datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 8, 30, 25, 430000, tzinfo=tzlocal())). I would like to convert this date values into ISO Format. Purpose being CloudWatch Log Insight could not read this date format.

**Output:**

```
[{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 8, 30, 25, 430000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'type': 'ExecutionFailed', 'id': 22, 'previousEventId': 21, 'executionFailedEventDetails': {'error': 'States.TaskFailed', 'cause': '{"AllocatedCapacity":2,"Attempt":0,"CompletedOn":1630485024021,"ErrorMessage":"An error occurred while calling o80.getDynamicFrame. The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.31.17.102, port 1433 has failed. Error: \\"Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.\\".","ExecutionTime":100,"GlueVersion":"2.0","Id":"jr_504a3acc2cdb7e3e18d2d22d8df69747744030e24afbcbee7f02de1ece6599c3","JobName":"sqlserver-ingest","JobRunState":"FAILED","LastModifiedOn":1630485024021,"LogGroupName":"/aws-glue/jobs","MaxCapacity":2.0,"NumberOfWorkers":2,"PredecessorRuns":[],"StartedOn":1630484906355,"Timeout":2880,"WorkerType":"G.1X"}'}}]
```

Comment: Show us the input data...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `for i in lst: i['timestamp'] = i['timestamp'].isoformat()`…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime to ISO 8601 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807201/datetime-to-iso-8601-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [datetime.isoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)

```
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal

dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 8, 30, 25, 430000, tzinfo=tzlocal())
dt_iso = dt.isoformat()
print(type(dt_iso), dt_iso)
```

```
<class 'str'> 2021-09-01T08:30:25.430000+00:00
```