# How should I store times with timezones in postgresql using python3?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, time, pytz

I've been reading about best practices for handling datetimes in Python and for storing them into postgresql (using utc as much as I can, with pytz for conversions, avoiding the tzinfo parameter in datetime constructor, etc...).

But my doubt now is that I'm surprised not finding anything about the **datetime.time** object and its best practices.

For the sake of example, imagine I want to store only a time, like 20:30, because I'm scheduling some task every week a couple of days on that time, but the day in the week could change every week. And probably the user has entered the time in his/her timezone. In my situation it would be a user in the Spanish timezone 'Europe/Madrid'.

My questions are:

- 1) Once I get the time as a datetime.time, how do I should store the
  timezone info into a datetime.time variable. Is it ok to use

  `datetime.time(h, m, s, ms, tzinfo=pytz_spanish_timezone)`
  ???
- 2) If not with the former
  line of code, how do I localize properly a naive time? datetime.datetime uses
  `my_datetime.localize(pytz_spanish_timezone)`
- 3) How do I convert one datetime.time object from a timezone to
  another, given that with datetime and pytz it would be using

  `new_tz_datetime = my_datetime.astimezone(pytz_spanish_timezone)`

  but with time there is no similar method
- 4) How should I store the datetime.time in postgresql database? I
  know there are time and timetz data types. I suppose I should store
  the time as UTC. Would the timezone matter? Should I store it somehow?
- 5) How to parse a time from a string without going through datetime? (I've made myself a function, but I'm sure there must exist some way using datetime or some robust module that probably covers cases I do not).

Comment: Maybe you could store your dates in epoch time?

Comment: And what about the timezone?

Comment: epoch time is automatically UTC.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: I was reading now but, how do you define, for example, 20:30 with epoch? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Well, I have already learnt from my own experience not to do (1).

Comment: I found this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2) [H]ow do I localize properly a naive time? `datetime.datetime` uses `my_datetime.localize(pytz_spanish_timezone)`

Actually, it is the other way around. `localize` is a pytz timezone method, not a `datetime` method:

```
import pytz
madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
aware_datetime = madrid.localize(naive_datetime)
```

You need a `datetime.datetime` here. There is no equivalent for `datetime.time` objects. See below for the reason why.

> 3) How do I convert one `datetime.time` object from a timezone to another?

Consider the following situation: We know the time is 20:30 and the timezone is `Europe/Madrid` and we wish to convert it to UTC.
The result will be different depending on whether or not the date falls within Daylight Savings Time (CEST) or not (CET):
For example,

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz
madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
utc = pytz.utc

CET_date = madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 3, 30, 20, 30, 0), is_dst=None)
# the most recent transition occurred at `2019-03-31 02:00:00+01:00 CEST` 
CEST_date = madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 20, 30, 0), is_dst=None)
print(CET_date.astimezone(utc))
print(CEST_date.astimezone(utc))

# 2019-03-30 19:30:00+00:00
# 2019-03-31 18:30:00+00:00
```

Notice that when the date is in CET, the time 20:30 is "converted" to 19:30, but when the date is in CEST, the time is converted to 18:30. 
There is no (simple) answer to your question without first knowing the date.

> 4a) How should I store the `datetime.time` in postgresql database? I know there are time and timetz data types.

Per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.

I think the docs are alluding to the issue shown above. Don't use `time with
time zone`.  If you want to store a time, use the PostgreSQL plain `time` type.

You could store the `time` and the `timezone` in the database, and reconstitute
a timezone-aware datetime later once you have a date. But note that there are
pitfalls:

1. There are ambiguous local datetimes

   ```
   import datetime as DT
   import pytz
   madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
   date = madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 2, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
   ```

   raises `pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2019-10-27 02:00:00`.
   To avoid the `AmbiguousTimeError`, `is_dst` must be specified explicitly:

   ```
   import datetime as DT
   import pytz
   madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
   date = madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 2, 0, 0), is_dst=False)
   print(date)
   date = madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 2, 0, 0), is_dst=True)
   print(date)

   # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+01:00
   # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+02:00
   ```
2. There are nonexistent local datetimes

   ```
   import datetime as DT
   import pytz
   madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
   madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 2, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
   ```

   raises `pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2019-03-31 02:00:00`

   You can avoid the NonExistentTimeError by specifying whether or not the naive localtime refers to a time during DST (Daylight Savings Time):

   ```
   import datetime as DT
   import pytz
   madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')

   date = madrid.normalize(madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 2, 0, 0), is_dst=False))
   print(date)
   date = madrid.normalize(madrid.localize(DT.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 2, 0, 0), is_dst=True))
   print(date)

   # 2019-03-31 03:00:00+02:00
   # 2019-03-31 01:00:00+01:00
   ```
3. There can be datetimes which are unrepresentable given a local datetime and a particular timezone.

   The `AmbiguousTimeError` and `NonExistentTimeError` above show the importance of specifying the value of `is_dst`.
   To avoid these errors you would need to store a boolean `is_dst` along with `time` and `timezone` in the database.

   You might think that you could avoid the problem simply choosing one value of
   `is_dst` for all times.  But you'd be mistaken.  Here is a peculiar example
   (taken from [the pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)) which shows if you
   always choose `is_dst = False` (or `is_dst = True`) there can be UTC datetimes
   which can not be expressed given just a naive localtime and a timezone!

   ```
   import datetime as DT
   import pytz

   warsaw = pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw')
   utc = pytz.utc

   date1 = warsaw.localize(DT.datetime(1915, 8, 4, 23, 35, 59), is_dst=False).astimezone(utc)
   date2 = warsaw.localize(DT.datetime(1915, 8, 4, 23, 36, 0), is_dst=False).astimezone(utc)
   print('Datetimes between {} and {} can not be expressed if we assume is_dist=False.'.format(date1, date2))

   date3 = warsaw.localize(DT.datetime(1915, 8, 4, 23, 59, 59), is_dst=True).astimezone(utc)
   date4 = warsaw.localize(DT.datetime(1915, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0), is_dst=True).astimezone(utc)
   print('Datetimes between {} and {} can not be expressed if we assume is_dist=True.'.format(date1, date2))
   ```

   prints

   ```
   Datetimes between 1915-08-04 22:11:59+00:00 and 1915-08-04 22:36:00+00:00 can not be expressed if we assume is_dist=False.
   Datetimes between 1915-08-04 22:11:59+00:00 and 1915-08-04 22:36:00+00:00 can not be expressed if we assume is_dist=True.
   ```

> 4b) I suppose I should store the time as UTC. Would the timezone matter? Should I store it somehow?

For the reasons shown above there is no such thing as a time (without a date) in UTC.
But you can avoid the problems mentioned above by simplying storing *datetimes* in UTC.

If you create a table with a column with `timestamptz` data type, then 
you can use a database adapter such as `psycopg2` to store Python timezone-aware datetimes
as PostgreSQL `timestamptz`s. When you query the database, `psycopg2` will convert the `timestamptz`s back into
timezone-aware datetimes for you.

Internally, PostgreSQL stores all `timestamptz`s in UTC, but it reports  the values with respect to 
the PostgreSQL user's timezone setting. On the Python side, given a timezone-aware datetime,
you can use its `astimezone` method to convert it to any timezone you like.

You don't need to store the timezone separately unless you want to report 
different datetimes with respect to different timezones.

> 5) How to parse a time from a string without going through datetime?

You could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to parse time strings:

```
import re
import datetime as DT
atime = DT.time(*map(int, re.search(r'(\d{,2}):(\d{,2}):(\d{,2})', 'blueberry jam at 13:32:02').groups()))
print(repr(atime))
# datetime.time(13, 32, 2)
```

Above, the regex pattern `\d` matches a single digit. `\d{1,2}` matches 1 or 2 digits.

Alternatively, the 3rd-party [dateutil package](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can parse
time strings in a variety of formats:

```
import dateutil.parser as DP
print(DP.parse("13:32:02").time())
# 13:32:02

print(DP.parse("blueberry jam at 13:32:02", fuzzy=True).time())
# 13:32:02

print(DP.parse("30 minutes 12 hours").time())
# 12:30:00

print(DP.parse("2:30pm").time())
# 14:30:00
```

---

There is a lot to digest here, and there is probably more that could be said
about each of these issues. In the future, you may want to split your post into
multiple questions. This will lower the barrier for people who may wish to
answer one question but not all of them, and will help you get more answers quicker.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer, but I just wanted to emphasize on the fact that at (5) I was asking how to parse a time, not a datetime. Also when I said "without going through datetime" I didn't mean the module. I was referring not to use a datetime.datetime object instead of a datetime.time object.

Comment: Great answer, by the way. I'm so grateful. Thanks again.