# Requests - Unable to Post date in ISO 8601 format in JSON Body

Tags: python, json, api, python-datetime, symantec

I want to build a script that run daily, to retrieve (yesterday date - today date) data.

A code to get today, yesterday date in ISO 8601, since the application only accept ISO 8601 format.

```
currDate = datetime.datetime.now()
prevDate = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
currDateISO = currDate.isoformat()
prevDateISO = prevDate.isoformat()
```

Post above ISO date into Request body.

```
DATA = \
    {'verb': 'query', \
    'start_time': prevDateISO, \
    'end_time': currDateISO \
    }

res=requests.post(Host + url, headers=Header, data=json.dumps(DATA), verify=False)
```

**Error (Python):**

```
 'error': 'invalid parameter', 'message': 'Error in field start_time: Time format must be ISO8601'}
```

Taking out the start/end time, worked in my Python codes.

**I was able to Post using below syntax:**

```
{
  "verb":"query",
  "start_time":"2019-12-17T15:39:55.616Z",
  "end_time":"2019-12-18T15:39:55.616Z"
}
```

Comment: I can't get what the issue actually is. Can you provide more details?

Comment: If you are getting the error in the API request why don't you try to put the date manually (as a string) then test the request? If you don't get an error see what's the difference between Python's iso date and the one you need.

Comment: Thanks @HenryHarutyunyan. I want to retrieve a data from this Symantecc ATP (API) . The request body (start-end time) only accept date in ISO format. I want to to tell the script, to get today & tomorrow date & post the request. Meaning, "start_time" will get yesterday's date. Similar like query condition;  Yesterday - Now. Sorry, I'm not really experts in programming terms.

Comment: np. But I guess you are receiving an error from the API. Can you try setting the dates manually? I mean just use strings of some random dates and see what the response is.

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan, I mention that in my question. Using full ISO date is working.

Comment: Ok then you can use `strftime` to convert the date to your desired format in stead of the python's `isodate` method.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Answer (score 1):

```
currDateISO = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
prevDateISO = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
```

[ISO time (ISO 8601) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python)