# Python (datetime) timezone conversion off by 4 minutes

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

when I run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz
from pytz import timezone

time = "2020-01-15 10:14:00"
time = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print("time1 = " + str(time))

time = time.replace(tzinfo=timezone('America/New_York'))
print("time2 = " + str(time))

time = time.astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC')) # explicity convert to UTC time
print("time3 = " + str(time))

time = datetime.strftime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  # output format
print("done time4 = " + str(time))
```

I get this output:

```
time1 = 2020-01-15 10:14:00
time2 = 2020-01-15 10:14:00-04:56
time3 = 2020-01-15 15:10:00+00:00
done time4 = 2020-01-15 15:10:00
```

I would have expected the final time to be "2020-01-15 15:14:00" anyone have any ideas why it's off by 4 mintutes?  I don't understand why the offset in time2 would by "-04:56" instead of "-05:00"

Comment: 2021: as we have Python 3.9 for a while now, awoid pytz's "localize trap" by using [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[From pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

> This library differs from the documented Python API for tzinfo implementations; if you want to create local wallclock times you need to use the `localize()` method documented in this document. In addition, if you perform date arithmetic on local times that cross DST boundaries, the result may be in an incorrect timezone (ie. subtract 1 minute from 2002-10-27 1:00 EST and you get 2002-10-27 0:59 EST instead of the correct 2002-10-27 1:59 EDT).

So, you are using pytz incorrectly.

<s>Following is both correct, and erroneous code</s> Following code shows results of your use of pytz (`datetime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone)`), and the recommended way of using pytz with datetime (`pytz.timezone.localize(datetime)`).

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timezone
from dateutil import tz
import pytz


d = date(2019, 1, 27)
t = time(19, 32, 00)

t1 = datetime.combine(d, t)
t1_epoch = t1.timestamp()
print("t1_epoch " + str(t1_epoch))
print("t1 " + str(t1))


# your approach/code
nytz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
t3 = t1.replace(tzinfo=nytz)
t3_epoch = t3.timestamp()
print("t3_epoch " + str(t3_epoch))
print("t3 " + str(t3))

# recommended approach/code using localize
nytz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
t6 = nytz.localize(t1)
t6_epoch = t6.timestamp()
print("t6_epoch " + str(t6_epoch))
print("t6 " + str(t6))
```

Output of above code:

```
t1_epoch 1548617520.0
t1 2019-01-27 19:32:00
t3_epoch 1548635280.0
t3 2019-01-27 19:32:00-04:56
t6_epoch 1548635520.0
t6 2019-01-27 19:32:00-05:00
```

`t3` is what you are doing, and it is giving incorrect offset (-4:56). Note that POSIX time is also incorrect in this case. POSIX time, by definition, does not change with timezone.

`t6` has been created using `pytz.timezone.localize()` method, and gives correct UTC offset (-5:00).

**Update**: Updated language of the answer as [one user found the answer confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996205/python-datetime-timezone-conversion-off-by-4-minutes/60997657?noredirect=1#comment107932932_60997657).

Comment: Although correct, the answer seems rather confusing to me (correct AND erroneous code?). Basically, the answer is: use `localize()` from the `timezone` class of the `pytz` module instead of `replace()` from the `datetime` class. Btw., to check a UTC offset, you could simply use `dt.utcoffset() / timedelta(hours=1)` (assuming `dt` is an aware `datetime` object).

Comment: @MrFuppes I've updated the "correct, and erroneous code" part to avoid confusion (though there was a serial comma to disambiguate). And yes, we can get offset using the code you've suggested. OP was already using `str(datetime.datetime)` so it made sense to this to display offset.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary you're the best! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but I've got this exact problem today when converting dates from `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone to UTC forward and backward. But for my case it is off by 6 minutes.

Merging the solution offered by @narendra-choudhary I got this:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
# Simulating unaware date created by user in front-end
in_date = datetime.now()
z = pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")
aware_localized_date = z.localize(in_date)
# Now converting to UTC
utc_date = aware_localized_date.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
print(utc_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
print(in_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

The output is:

```
>>> print(utc_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
11/06/2021 21:56:02
>>> print(in_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
11/06/2021 18:56:02
>>>
```

My code it's working now thanks to @narendra-choudhary! I hope it helps for those who got confused.

Comment: python datetime timezone conversion off by 6 minutes hoping google spy bots got this

Comment: it is safe and simpler to use `datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo"))` - one of the occasions where you don't need to localize explicitly with pytz's timezone class.