# python unix timestamp not match with different timezone

Tags: python, datetime

when print the following timestamp utc Jan 30 2021, I am expecting they are the same. why there is a 340 difference?

```
start = datetime(2021, month=1, day=30, hour=21, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
start1 = datetime(2021, month=1, day=30, hour=16, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(start.timestamp())
print(start1.timestamp())
```

output:

1612040400.0

1612040160.0

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996205/python-datetime-timezone-conversion-off-by-4-minutes