# How can I format the datetime tuple returned by python from mysql

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, pymysql

My python is running a query and returns the output txn_time as shown below.

```
    try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=db, user=user,
                                 password=pwd,
                                 db=db_name)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(**txn_query**.format(a,b,c))
        return cursor.fetchall()
except:
```

txn_query= "SELECT txn_time FROM transactions WHERE CUSTOMERID in (12345) txn_type IN (111) ORDER BY 1 DESC"

Output:
(datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 25, 10, 6, 29),)

I need to format it to the time: 2020-08-25 10:06:29
Tried to format is using strftime but couldn't achieve. Can someone help help or guide me to the right pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Comment: @manveti: the output that the OP gets is a datetime object, not unix timestamp. Could simply format to string by `.isoformat(' ')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO time (ISO 8601) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple actually - in my case the result set returned a tuple so i just had to access the first element which had my result set. And then it automatically converted the time back to what was seen in the DB.

```
#before
print(result)
(datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 25, 10, 6, 29),)


#after
result = result[0] #first element of the returned tuple
print(result)
2020-08-26 02:01:01
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take the datetime object out of the tuple with this: `txn_time = txn_time[0]`. Then, simply use this: `txn_time_str = txn_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`! This should put the string you want into a variable called `txn_time_str`.

Comment: this was fine, txn_time = txn_time[0]
but that txn_time_str didn't work for me, thanks anyway