# Parse date in python to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, date

I am trying to parse this column to a column containing the weekday. Eg. 0-6 or 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...

```
0    2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000
1    2020-10-06 09:48:10.000000
2    2020-10-06 14:19:27.000000
3    2020-10-05 10:21:22.000000
4    2020-10-05 13:35:06.000000
Name: charging_start, dtype: object
```

I am sorry for the beginner question, but I am one. I was playing with datetime, but could not make it work. This was my last approach:

```
from datetime import date

test = '2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000'
print("\n{}\n".format(test))
print(date.fromisoformat(test))
```

Resulting to:

```
2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-318-81788367097a> in <module>
     13 
     14 test = '2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000'
---> 15 print(date.fromisoformat(test))

ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python#28147286 does this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
from datetime import datetime

test = '2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000'
print("\n{}\n".format(test))
print(datetime.fromisoformat(test))
```

Output

```
2020-10-06 03:39:51.000000

2020-10-06 03:39:51
```

For this case is better to use the `datetime` class instead of the `date` class since you are parsing a datetime value and not just a date. 
If the test value was `test = '2020-10-06'` then the `date` class `fromisoformat()` method was parsing the test value.

Comment: Thanks. I am playing with Jupyter notebook and there it was print(datetime..datetime.fromisoformat(test))

Comment: Or print(datetime.datetime.strptime(co_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")) => probably not suitable for this example, but good to keep in mind.