# In python To get specified month & date for example: dec-18,19,20 jan-3,4,5

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bbml.png)

i have DataFrame as above.

**Expected output**
dec-18,19,20 jan-3,4,5

Comment: And for your dates treatments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python/28147286#28147286

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df.groupby('month').agg({'date': lambda x: ",".join(set(x))})
```