# datetime to ISO-8601 format

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views, iso8601

I have Django project and I want to use parse_datetime() to get (ISO-8601) formatted

not in templates

I have this datetime (2022-06-04 15:23:08.367007+00:00)

I want it to be like this format (2022-06-04T15:30:00Z)

I have tried this like this

```
datetime_test = '2022-06-04 15:23:08.367007+00:00'
datetime_test_1 = dateparse.parse_datetime(str(datetime_test))
print(datetime_test_1)
```

I got

```
2022-06-04 15:23:08.367007+00:00
```

Is there any way I can get ISO-8601 format
like this format

```
2022-06-04T15:30:00Z
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python) may help.

Comment: `.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`?