# How to convert date/time to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000+000 format?

Tags: python, python-datetime

How to convert DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000+0000 format using Python.

I want to convert this

```
20-05-2022 14:03:02
```

to

```
2022-05-20T14:03:02.000+0000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO time (ISO 8601) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use the datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dtt = datetime.strptime("20-05-2022 14:03:02", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dtt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds"))
```

Prints `2022-05-20T14:03:02.000+00:00`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147286/8524301) for python datetime and ISO 8601.

Comment: If I want to convert 20-05-2022 14:03:02.000 to iso format how to do that